# Обход ArrayList через for или iterator?

Tags: java

Собственно в java я начинающий. Задался таким вопросом в каких случаях надо использовать for, а в каких можно воспользоваться итератором? И что из них работает быстрее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нано-оптимизацией будете заниматься, в любом случае, не сейчас. Делайте то, что для вас удобнее! Но вообще, где-то было указано, что предпочтительнее пользоваться итератором. Вот только где, не знаю.

**UPD1**: 
Итераторы очень легковесны. Поэтому в Java его реализация поддерживает перемещение только в одном направлении.
Плюс итератор может понадобиться в том случае, если вы захотите написать универсальный код, который не будет зависеть от типа контейнера (`List`, `Set` и т.д.).
Либо просто в некоторых ситуациях так красивее выглядеть будет. 
Остальное вы уже откроете сами.

Comment: Я просто хочу понять разницу между этими 2-мя подходами... Мне это нужно скорее для общего развития.

Comment: Мне кажется итератор был актуалем до 5й джавы, сейчас, в коллекциях, где нету индексов, предпочтительней пользоватся конструкцией форыч )))

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Если коллекция (ArrayList) в цикле доступа по итератору может меняться произвольным образом, то доступ по итератору попросту **правильно не работает**. Вплоть до того, что программа валится.

Естественно, итераторы требуют ресурсов и снижают производительность, однако код получается более красивым (но красота понятие субъективное).

Почему-то толком это нигде не описано. Можете проверить сами и сделать соответствующие выводы.